# using arrays to store information and retrieving them with php

Tags: php, arrays

for example, i have

`<a href="FashionDetails.php?menu_id=1"></a>`
`<a href="FashionDetails.php?menu_id=2"></a>`
`<a href="FashionDetails.php?menu_id=3"></a>`
`<a href="FashionDetails.php?menu_id=4"></a>`

and the process page:
`   $fashion_id = $_GET['menu_id'];

```
if ($menu_id == "1") {
    $id = "1";
    $menu_name ="Business Fashion";
    $img_file ="images/mushroomsoup.jpg";
    $description ="mushroom soup";
    $color ="red";
}
elseif($menu_id =="2") {
    $id ="2";
    $menu_name ="minestrone soup";
    $img_file ="images/mine.jpg";
    $description ="minestrone soup";
    $color ="blue"; 
}
elseif($menu_id =="3") {
    $id="3";
    $menu_name ="carrot soup";
    $img_file ="images/carrot.jpg";
    $description ="carrot soup.";
    $color ="green";
}
elseif ($menu_id =="4"){
    $id="4";
    $menu_name ="shark fin";
    $img_file ="images/sharkfin.jpg";
    $description ="sharkfin.";
    $color ="gray";
}



    echo "<h1 style='text-align: center'>Welcome to my restaurant!</h1>";
    echo "<font color=$color>You have selected $menu_name</font>. Menu ID($id)<br/>";
    echo "<img src='$img_file'></img><br/>";
    echo "$description";

    ?>
```

'
Let's say I want to use array() function instead of using if-else statement, how can I do it? I understand there's a easier method by using a sql statement but I've not been taught sql yet and right now I can only use php. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of `cases` ?

Comment: There is no way to use an array() in place of if else.

Comment: @superphonic sure there is, if the if else is comparing equality to a numeric constant, you just have an array with the output data/actions/functions to call in that array slot.

Comment: @Dan Yep, your absolutely right...

Comment: @DainisAbols is is the switch and case function? i think so.

Comment: @Dan I just started learning php.. and wow seeing the way you guys explain is a little confusing.. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$menus = array(
    1 => array(
        'menu_name'   => "Business Fashion",
        'img_file'    => "images/mushroomsoup.jpg",
        'description' => "mushroom soup",
        'color'       => "red"
    ),
    2 => array(
        'menu_name'   => "minestrone soup",
        'img_file'    => "images/mine.jpg",
        'description' => "minestrone soup",
        'color'       => "blue"
    ),
);

// Print out the menu name for menu ID #1
echo $menus[$menu_id]['menu_name']; // Business Fashion
```

Basically you put your menu items in an array (of arrays) and then access them using the menu ID you get from for query string.

To put this into a table you would use a simple loop:

```
foreach ($menus as $id => $menu) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $menu['menu_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $menu['img_file']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $menu['description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $menu['color']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php   
}
```

You obviously need to alter that to suit your needs but should give you the idea. If you need the menu ID you just echo out `$id`.

Comment: That's exactly what I said.

Comment: Although this is what OP asked for, I would still suggest to go with [Amal Murali](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20952433/1488915) suggestion.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Unfortunately I was unable to read your mind and composed this while you composed your answer.

Comment: @DainisAbols why? He said he was still learning, it could be a good exercise. Not to mention an array-based menu is way more scalable.

Comment: @JohnConde why do we always miss that mindreading ability ... ;-).

Comment: @BartFriederichs If we could do it we wouldn't be programmers. We'd be in the circus instead. :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yes, for learning it might be interesting, but not exactly good practice to do so.

Comment: @DainisAbols disagree again. It makes for a flexible, scalable menu system. You can even add submenus and all.

Comment: @DainisAbols Amal Murali's answer is more cumbersome in maintenance. this answer only requires that the array be updated when the menu is. as the OP mentioned, a database would be better as it could populate the menu page as well

Comment: yup @JohnConde that's it!! I'm just wondering, is it possible to organise the information into a table with the <tr> and <td> function? I've been trying it and I can't seem to write out the correct code.

Comment: @Glenn See my up[dated answer for how to output a table from this array.

Comment: @JohnConde if it's referring from my Fashiondetails page, I need to add <td><?php echo $menu[menu_id]['menu_name']; ?></td> am i right? However I tried and it said Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Make sure the menu_id matches a key in your $menus array. If it doesn't exist you will get this error.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [`switch()`](http://php.net/switch) construct.

From the PHP manual documentation:

> The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for.

So, your code will look like:

```
switch ($menu_id) {
    case '1':
        # code
        break;
    case '2':
        #code
        break;

    ...

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$menu = array(
   "1"=>array(
      "id"=>1,
      "menu_name"=>"shark fin";
      ...
   )
   ...
)
```

Then use `$entry = $menu[$menu_id]` to get the entry, and `$id = $entry["id"]`, etc to get the parts. Don't forget to make sure `$menu_id` is actually valid. You can easily type in `<a href="FashionDetails.php?menu_id=6"> </a>`. (Strange fashion, BTW.)

Good luck in learning PHP!

Comment: haha, that's cause im doing my school's assignment. I did the <a href=...> initially and an advance feature we can use is to use array to store the information.. Thanks for the help anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch case statements.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php